# Kentico CKEditor Configure Style Set Dynamically

Tags: kentico, ckeditor.net

I'm using Kentico 9 and I'd like to be able to use different CK Editor style sets on different pages. I have added a style set to the styles.js file as follows.

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add("mystyles", [{ name: "testone", element: "p" }]);
```

Then in the page I've added some JS as per the CK Editor web site.

```
if (CKEDITOR.currentInstance) {
    CKEDITOR.currentInstance.config.stylesSet = "mystyles";
}
```

When I load the page containing the CK Editor, the style drop down contains the default style set, not the custom one I defined.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved my issue. I added the following to styles.js:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add("my-styles", [
    { name: "Paragraph", element: "p" },
    { name: "Heading 1", element: "h1" }
]);
```

Then, in the master page for the area of my site that needs to use the "my-styles" style set, I added:

```
<script>window.ckstyleset = "my-styles"</script>
```

Finally, in config.js I added:

```
var styleset = window.ckstyleset ? window.ckstyleset : "default";

config.stylesSet = styleset;
```

Using this approach I was able to customise the styles listed in the drop down depending on what master page was is use.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it right you need to define your new toolbarset in *config.js* (CMSAdminControls/CKEditor/config.js) dropdown.

Something like:

```
config.toolbar_Basic = [
['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'InsertLink', 'Unlink']
];
```

The other thing - you need to add new option to this dropdown in **Webparts** application > EditableText webpart> Properties > HTMLAreaToolbar > DataSource
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's not the toolbar set that I'm working on. It's the styles drop down in the toolbar set. I'm wanting to load the styles in the drop down based on the page the editor is in. Some pages needs different styles in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Defining+styles+for+the+editor) you need to read.

The dropdown styles are defined in `CMS\CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\styles.js`, such as:

```
{ name: 'Italic Title',     element: 'h2', styles: { 'font-style': 'italic' } },
```

You define the name of the style (the name appears in the dropdown), and then the element and style(s) that should be applied.

After editing the file, make sure you **clear your browser cache**.
As most Kentico admin interface pages are nested and `iframe`'d, the caching is pretty agressive, and your styles might not appear until cache is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just javascript after all, so you can simply check the url in some if statement or in some switch-case and then apply styles you need. Do you need some code example? You should be able to find many of them on the internet :)